# Capture Action Query Warnings in vba (MS Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to capture (via vba) the information from the "warnings" that pop up when running an action query in MS Access?

As in: When an update query is run, I'd like to capture how many records are to be updated, and compare that against another variable in my code.

And if it's possible, I'd like to keep warnings set to off! I guess I'm looking to see if there is any way to customize the action query warnings. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-action-query-confirmation-messages-on-or-off-e58e4bba-9d54-4b9d-b962-9eca048e5335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Execute` method of ADO (see answer @Michael Z.) or DAO:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "SELECT * INTO someschema.sometable FROM someschema.anothertable", dbFailOnError
MsgBox db.RecordsAffected
```

Querydefs also have `RecordsAffected` property. Avoid using `DoCmd.RunSQL` commands.

Comment: Why should I avoid DoCmd.RunSQL commands? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Because you will need to suppress error messages and don't have access to RecordsAffected property. Error suppressing affects whole application, if you won't enable it back due, for instance, error, even form/report/query builders won't ask you about saving

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-setwarnings-method-access

To obtain rows affected you'd have to run the queries like this.

```
Dim recordsAffected As Long
cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO someschema.sometable FROM someschema.anothertable", _
           recordsAffected
MsgBox recordsAffected
```

Comment: Also need to declare and set the cn object variable?

Comment: Yes, but I figure OP should already have that. I'll update the answer in a little bit.